# Add class to other as property

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to add my custom NSObject class to other as property, is that possible?

Class look like this:

```
@interface PlaceHolder : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *description;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *webPage;
```

I want to make it property of my other class to initialize it once, and then work with properties - name, description. webpage and other..

Do i need to create a category? Or there is another way to achieve this?

Any advice would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a property to the class that needs to use it

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) PlaceHolder *placeHolder;
```